# Synaptic Package Manager: the Properties and Search buttons

Tags: synaptic

In the new version of [Synaptic](https://github.com/mvo5/synaptic), the **Properties** and **Search** buttons are aligned on the right.

How can I move the Search and Properties buttons to the left hand side?

I tried to replace the file `/usr/share/synaptic/gtkbuilder/window_main.ui` but it didn't work.

These distros all exhibit the same problem:

| ISO | Synaptic version |
| --- | --- |
| ubuntu-mate-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso | 0.90.2 |
| debian-live-testing-amd64-mate+nonfree.iso | 0.90.2 |
| ubuntu-mate-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso | 0.84.6 |
| linuxmint-20.1-mate-64bit.iso | 0.84.6 |

> [image: Synaptic on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS]

No problem:

- Linux Mint 19.3 MATE and Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS with Synaptic 0.84.3

  > [image: Synaptic on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]

See also [Synaptic Package Manager Regression?](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=324058&sid=3b1619133f711542032f0759e4d86dac)

Comment: You have to report your finding as bug-report.

Comment: I was sending 2 emails to the developer (Michael Vogt). He didn't answer.
I don't have a github account. I don't know how to submit a bug report to github.

Comment: It's very easy to submit a bug report on Github: Create a Github account, click on the **Issues** tab of the repository and click the big green **New Issue** button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking this as bug-report then it is off-topic here.

If you are asking for the local solution which you are ready to apply by yourself, then you have to install special application named GTK+ User Interface Builder (`glade`) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install glade
```

and then edit needed `/usr/share/synaptic/gtkbuilder/window_main.ui` file in it to have your locally patched Synaptic.